# The limit of an integration

Tags: integration, limits

Assume that I have a real-valued positive function $f(x)$, and I need to find the following limit:

$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y x e^{-y f(x)}dx$. What approaches can I follow to find the limit?

My exact function is $f(x)=a_{1}x^3+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x$, where $a_3,a_2,a_1$ are positive constants. But I'm also interested in learning about general approaches to solve this problem.

My approach:

The given integration is upper-bounded as follows:

$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y x e^{-y (a_{1}x^3+a_{2}x^2+a_{3}x)}dx \leq \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y x e^{-y (a_{2}x^2)}dx=\frac{1}{2a_2}$

And we also know that it is positive, so the limit is bounded between 
$0$ and $\frac{1}{2a_2}$ and it is finite. However, I can't exchange the order of the limit and the integration since this will result in $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} 0 dx$. I know that I should check the dominated convergence theorem to be able to do so, but even if the conditions of it are satisfied, changing the order will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $f(x)=a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x$, with $a_i>0$, we have

$$xye^{-yf(x)}\le \frac{x}{ef(x)}=\frac{1}{e(a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3)}\in L^1$$

Hence, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{y\to \infty}\int_0^\infty xye^{-yf(x)}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \lim_{y\to \infty}\left(xye^{-yf(x)}\right)\,dx=0$$

And we are done!

Comment: Can you please explain to me how did you get the upper-bound?

Comment: Sure.  For $f(x)=xe^{-ax}$, $f'(x)=(1-ax)e^{-ax}=0$ at $x=1/a$, where $f$ is a maximum.